# Apache Configuration for laravel installation on directadmin

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, httpd.conf

I am trying to install Laravel on vps with Direct admin. Below is my Apache config file

```
<VirtualHost MYIP:80 >
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@chat.am
    DocumentRoot /home/mydir/domains/domain.com/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydir/domains/domain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup mydir mydir
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/mydir/domains/domain.com/public_html>
            php_admin_flag safe_mode OFF
            php_admin_flag engine ON
            php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f chat$
            php_admin_value mail.log /home/mydir/.php/php-mail.log
            php_admin_value open_basedir /home/mydir/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/loc$
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

According to the Laravel manual I have to point to the `public` directory. After I set `doc root` to `/home/mydir/domains/domain.com/public_html/public` I get this error when I try to access `domain.com`

> 500 Internal Server Error

UPDATE: `/var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.error.log` contains this Laravel error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/mydir/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411

Comment: Open /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.error.log and look what the apache writes in this errorlog if you try to access this directory.

Comment: If the mentioned errorlog above is empty, check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois just updated my question.. iam checking for apache error...

Comment: There is your error: `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/mydir/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411`. Fix this PHP error (this error message says everything you need to know) and it should work.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois that error is due to redirection, bcos i am running the same code on different  server, it works fine...

Comment: That error doesn't appear due to redirection. It appears because the php source code has syntax errors. They don't appear just because you're using them on several servers.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois ok let me fix that issue first, then i will check apache error...

Comment: have u fixed the syntax error.

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` files in your root and public folder

Comment: @Friend I'm a bit confused. Why does the bounty description say "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."? there isn't even an answer. Or has it been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you have root access .. you can check your php version ...

```
php -v
```

upgrade it to php 5.4 .

i have installed Laravel in Directadmin successfully by using below .htaccess config file inside public folder ...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In direct admin you can change the apache config of Document root for specific domain inside

```
etc/httpd/conf.d/domians/yourdomian.conf
```

change it to ...

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domians/yourdomain/public"
```

Thats it ;) It should work fine  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation ;) let me check and get back to you ;)

Comment: If change the directadmin apache config, will it affect directadmin script. Because I've asked the support, they advice me better don't change it

Answer (score 4):

The problem here seems to be your PHP version. Line 411 in `helpers.php` is [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L411):

```
$results = [];
```

It is the short syntax for creating a new array as of PHP 5.4. see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

As the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements) states, Laravel 4.2 requires PHP >= 5.4

But the version on your server is probably lower, causing this error.

Obviously the best solution to this is **upgrading** to at least PHP 5.4.
If you can't upgrade, use Laravel 4.1 (requires PHP >= 5.3.7)